# Jquery de minha página não funciona após ser chamada por um XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Tenho o seguinte código que pega uma tabela em uma página php e traz a tabela para dentro de uma div no meu index.

Porém nesta minha página getreult.php tem codigos em jquery, mas eles não funcionam, e se eu quiser executar alguma função quando clickar em um botão que tem na getresult.php também não funciona, mesmo colocando os códigos jquery na index não funciona.

Já tive o mesmo problema uma vez, mas já faz tempo e não lembro mais como resolver.

```
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    document.getElementById("listview").innerHTML = this.responseText;
  }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "./app/getresult.php", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: Está faltando `"./app/getresult.php, true` fechar ...

Comment: O codigo está funcionando, ele chama a página pra minha div, só que o jquery que eu tinha na getresult.php não funciona, um simples alert não funciona, se eu acessar o endereço da página getresult.php no navegador ai o jquery funciona.

Comment: Verifique no console se ocorre algum tipo de erro e também você fechou as aspas como o wmsouza comentou?

Answer (score 0):

Bem uma das soluções é executar o código via jquery usando o método [.Load](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

```
function loadDoc(){  
    console.log( "Chamada." );
    $( "#listview" ).load( "./app/getresult.php", function() {
      console.log( "Doc carregado." );
    });     
};

$(function(){loadDoc();});
setInterval (loadDoc, 5000 );
```